# Get actual color of Qt widget's background

Tags: c++, qt

On my system, as you can see from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiqlU.png), the background of `QTabWidget` is lighter than the background of the window ( `#FCFCFC` vs `#EFEFEF` ).

[image: test window]

However, when I try to query the color,

```
auto tab = new QTabWidget;
tab->addTab(new QWidget, "Test");
setCentralWidget(tab);

auto color = tab->palette.brush(tab->backgroundRole()).color();
qDebug() << color.name() << '\n';
```

it still returns `#EFEFEF` (and none of other roles give me the right color).

How do I query the *actual* color?

Comment: Maybe you should do rather this: `tab->palette().color(tab->backgroundRole());`?

Comment: It returns exactly same thing.

Comment: There is no way to query the actual color. The widget's style is responsible for this - assuming that the widget is styled. And the styles will use the system palette and/or heuristics, etc. And on top of that there's CSS styling. The only portable way to do this is to render the widgets into an image and get the color value from the image.